# Different Zoom effect on Desktop and Mobile

Tags: javascript, css, zooming, css-transitions, background-size

I'm using this JS and CSS to add a zoom effect to header image. It's perfectly working on desktop.

Problem is on mobile hero image is not "filling" the entire container.

So I would need to have 2 different JS with 2 different % settings to make it work both on desktop and mobile.

**Is there a solution to make one script with my 2 differents needs you'll find below based on screen size ? "this function is for desktop, and this function is for mobile" ?**

*For the one who knows I'm using GeneratePress's Elements feature to display hero header entire site.*

**Here is the JS + CSS working for desktop :**

JS

```
<script>
var pagehero = document.querySelector('.page-hero');

function hero_animation(){
        pagehero.style.backgroundSize = 100+'%';
        pagehero.style.opacity = '1';
}
    
    document.onload = hero_animation();
</script>
```

CSS

```
.page-hero {
     transition: background-size 1s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86), opacity 1s ease-out 0.1s !important;
    opacity: 0; background-size: 150% auto;
}
```

**Here is the JS + CSS that I would need to add for mobile :**

JS

```
<script>
var pagehero = document.querySelector('.page-hero');

function hero_animation(){
        pagehero.style.backgroundSize = 200+'%';
        pagehero.style.opacity = '1';
}
    
    document.onload = hero_animation();
</script>
```

CSS

```
.page-hero {
     transition: background-size 1s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86), opacity 1s ease-out 0.1s !important;
    opacity: 0; background-size: 300% auto;
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the function when the document `html/body` is loaded.

```
<script>
var pagehero = document.querySelector('.page-hero');

function hero_animation(){
        pagehero.style.backgroundSize = 100+'%';
        pagehero.style.opacity = '1';
}
    
    document.onload = hero_animation();
</script>
```

Change it to this:

```
<script>
var pagehero = document.querySelector('.page-hero');

function hero_animation(){
        pagehero.style.backgroundSize = 100+'%';
        pagehero.style.opacity = '1';
}
    
    document.onload = hero_animation;
</script>
```

Or this:

```
<script>
var pagehero = document.querySelector('.page-hero');

function hero_animation(){
        pagehero.style.backgroundSize = 100+'%';
        pagehero.style.opacity = '1';
}
    
    document.onload = function() { hero_animation() };
</script>
```

Second, you should change `100/200` to a string. JavaScript is case-sensitive:

```
pagehero.style.backgroundSize = '100' + '%';
```

*Or*

```
pagehero.style.backgroundSize = (Number(100).toString()) + '%';
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but your propositions for the "document.onload" part are not working, both breaking the hero image.

By the way the behaviour I'm looking at is to have a zoom effect on hero image on page loading and the actual function I'm using is perfectly working on desktop. 

My problem is to use a different function on mobile. If you have a suggestion regarding my Mobile vs Desktop issue, I'll be glad.

Comment: Ok, I think what you're looking for is "Responsive Web Design". Check out at this: https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_responsive.asp; The problem is that you're setting absolute sizes in CSS that only match the viewport of your device. You need to use relative units/sizes in your styling so it matches the resize of the browser. And if you want a zoom effect, check out this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_zoom_hover.asp

Comment: No, it's not what I'm looking for. But thanks anyway !